# On Android 5.1 Device - No Scroll Indicator

Tags: codenameone

Scrolling through a list on a test device running Android 5.1 there are neither scroll bars nor indicators shown dragging over start or end of the list.

In the simulator using the Nexus 7 skin there are indicators.

What needs to be configured to show some indication on the scroll position of the list?

Comment: Without any further information no one will be able to help you on the issue. Which device is it? has it a customized theme or is it using the default?

Answer (score 0):

The theme needs to include the `Scroll` & `ScrollThumb` UIID's but I'm guessing your issue is with the [fadeScrollBarBool](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-theming.html) theme constant which you might want to define to `false`.

Comment: My test device is a Cubot X17 with Android 5.1.
The simulator shows scroll indicators.
Shoudn't the simulator behave roughly like the real device?
How can things like UUIDs be wrong when it works in the simulator?
And which versions of Android do the various simulator skins emulate?

Comment: It should be identical to the Xoom theme although the density is much higher on a modern Android device so there might be a difference.

Comment: Ok I checked again:
In the simulator I see the blue shading when trying to scroll beyond start or and of a list - and a scrollbar.
And on by Cobot X17 I see no blue shading and - actually there is a barely visible scrollbar so thin one can hardly see it. So is it a bug thet the shading is missing and shouldn't the scrollbar adapt itself to higher resolutions?

Comment: The default seems to be 1 pixel. I fixed it to be half a mm which should make it visible. It looks like the missing edge behavior is a bug. I've filed an issue to track this here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1680